# How do I make these 3 tabs each have individual background colors?

Tags: jquery, css

I have three tabs and I am looking for each tab background to have its own color. Right now they are all grey. How do I give tab 1, tab 2, and tab 3 individual colors?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/4zLkb6v0/

```
.tabs a:hover,
.tabs a.active {
 background: #666;
 color: #fff;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/4zLkb6v0/5/

essentially you could use your for attribute for each label:

```
.tabs .tab label[for='tab-1'] {
  background-color: red;
}
.tabs .tab label[for='tab-2'] {
  background-color: orange;
}
.tabs .tab label[for='tab-3'] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

perhaps a class on each label would be better, I would also clean up some of your nesting, too many DIVs nested inside each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the css nth-child property:

```
.tabs a:nth-child(1){
    background: red;
}
.tabs a:nth-child(2){
    background: blue;
}
.tabs a:nth-child(3){
    background: green;
}
```